# ODATA does not return JSON in MS Edge

Tags: json, odata, microsoft-edge

I'm requesting some data from an ODATA V2 service using the fetch api and want it to return in JSON format. That just works fine in Firefox and Chrome using the header `accept: 'application/json; odata=verbose'` but somehow MS Edge seems to ignore this header and returns xml instead.

The request itself has status `200` but I can't call `respone.json()` as it yields an error (but only in MS Edge).

Is there something else I need to add to the request or is it just a bug in MS Edge? I also tried to add `$format=json` to the url but with no appeal.

This is how the request is sent:

```
return fetch(window.location.origin + "/odata/v2/GraphService/Graph?$orderby=DATE desc", { headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
    }})
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json(); // this fails. response.text() works but yields xml
            } else {
                throw new Error('Request not ok');
            }
        })
        .then(j => j.d.results.map(e => {
            return {
                ID: e.ID,
                GRAPHNAME: e.GRAPHNAME
            }
        }))
        .catch(err => console.log(err.message));
```

Edit: I actually noticed it's not xml that is returned but html containing a redirect link (I blurred the URLs):

```
<html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" /><script>document.cookie="fragmentAfterLogin="+encodeURIComponent(location.hash)+";path=/";document.cookie="locationAfterLogin="+encodeURIComponent(location.href.split('#')[0].split(location.host)[1])+";path=/";document.cookie="signature=...;path=/";location="https://<some-url>/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<some-id>&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F<some-other-url.com>%2Flogin%2Fcallback"</script></head></html>
```

Comment: What is the detailed information of the error you get in Edge? Which version of Edge are you using? I guess you're using Edge Legacy and you can update to the [latest Edge Chromium](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge) that I think the issue will disappear in that version. Besides, OData Version 4.0 is the current recommended version of OData in the official site, you can also try to use that version.

Comment: @YuZhou I'm using Edge 42.17134.1098.0 which I guess is now obsolete? Well then I'll just wait for my company to update to the new Edge Chromium and until then tell the customer not to use Edge for our app. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Yes, it's the old version of Edge which now is called Edge Legacy. The new Edge is based on Chromium. Glad to help.